# Dynamic MVC Razor href based on active nav-tab

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC Razor project using Bootstrap where:

- A main view has nav-tabs
- The nav-tabs have a button and search field
- The active nav-tab loads a partial view below
- The partial view is a List

[Picture Of Main Nav-Tabs and partial view list loaded below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CSGK.png)

**I would like to have the "Create New" button and Search field urls change based on which tab is currently active.**

So, if inquiries are selected, then the "Create New" button would link to \inquiry\create\id

If Media is selected, then it would link to \media\create\id

The nav-tabs are defined like so:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#inquiries" data-toggle="tab">Inquiries</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#events" data-toggle="tab">Events</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#media" data-toggle="tab">Media</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class="form-group is-empty">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-8" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action(" Create ", "Inquiry ", new { id = Model.ID })">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                    <strong>Create New</strong>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="inquiries" role="tabpanel">
        @{Html.RenderAction("List", "Inquiry", new { id = Model.ID });}
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="events" role="tabpanel">
        @{Html.RenderAction("List", "Event", new { id = Model.ID });}
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="media" role="tabpanel">
        @{Html.RenderAction("List", "Media", new { id = Model.ID });}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried many different methods, but can't figure out how to get this working.  I constantly run into issues mixing Razor syntax and Javascript together.  I would greatly appreciate any feedback or suggestions that people may have to get me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically keep the create url link for each tag in the data attribute of each link listen for the `click` event. When clicked, read this data attribute value and set the create link's `href` value

```
<li class="active">
    <a href="#inquiries" 
     data-create="@Url.Action("Create","Inquiries")"
     class="tabLinks"  data-toggle="tab">Inquiries</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#events" data-create="@Url.Action("Create","Events")"
      class="tabLinks" data-toggle="tab">Events</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#media" data-create="@Url.Action("Create","Media")"
     class="tabLinks" data-toggle="tab">Media</a>
</li>

<a id="createLink" 
 href="@Url.Action("Create", "Home ", new { id = Model.ID })">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
     <strong>Create New</strong>
</a>
```

Now listen to the `click` event on these links, read the data attribute value and set it to the `href` property value of the create link.

```
$(function() {

     $(".tabLinks").click(function (e) {
          $("#createLink").attr("href", $(this).data("create"));
     });

});
```

You can do the same for the search form.